# Selecting values from an xml document object with XPATH in code behind (c#)

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to select specific values from a xml document using XPath. The xml is stored into a string varibale "tmp". This xml is the result of a query performed on a external API.

sample XML contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Results>
<Checks>
<Check id="wbc">
<Linespeed>6000 </Linespeed>
<Provider>BT WBC </Provider>
</Check>
<Check id="adsl">
<Linespeed>2048 </Linespeed>
<Provider>BT ADSL </Provider>
</Check>
</Checks>
</Results>
```

Using XPATH in code behind I want to be able to select the  and  only for id=adsl, then store the value in a string variable for later use. I want to achieve this withouth the use of a separate xslt stylesheet.

Here is the code I have written for this but I am getting an error:

```
//Creating an XPATH epression
String strExpression1;
strExpression1 = "Results/Checks/Check[@id = 'adsl']/Linespeed";

//Loading the xml document
XmlDocument doc;
doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(tmp);

//Create an XmlNamespaceManager to resolve the default namespace.
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("bk", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt");

//Selecting Linespeed from Check id='adsl'
XmlNode Check;
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
Check = root.SelectSingleNode(strExpression1, nsmgr);

//Assigning the the results of the XPATH expression to the variable Linespeedval
string Linespeedval = Check.ToString();

//Adding a control to display the xpath results of the "tmp" xml objectt
AvailabilityCheckerResults2.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(Linespeedval));
```

Any assistance will be greately appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I get no output, but the typical sharepoint error instead. I have debugged the code and the "tmp" xml document is being read stored into the root object. The problem seems to be with the XmlNode Check. Nothing is assigned to it, and further more nothing assigned to the string Linespeedval. This should work in theory but Is there a better or simpler way to achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
strExpression1 = "/Results/Checks/Check[@id = 'adsl']/Linespeed";
//or strExpression1 = "//Checks/Check[@id = 'adsl']/Linespeed";
//doc has no namespace
Check = root.SelectSingleNode(strExpression1);
....
string Linespeedval = Check.InnerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article. It has step by step instruction to parse xml using xpath.
[How to query XML with an XPath expression by using Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308333)